# Not able to bind data to view from an object in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a interface in Angular 2 as follows -

```
export interface ContactInformationModel {
    EmailAddress : string;
    DirectPhone : string;
    Extension : string;
    DirectFax : string;
    RemoteFax : string;
    PersonalEmail : string;
    HomePhone : string;
    CellPhone : string;
    Birthday : string;
    Address : string;
    PrimaryEmergencyContact : string;
    PrimaryEmergencyContactCellPhone : string;
    SecondaryEmergencyContact : string;
    SecondaryEmergencyContactCellPhone : string;
}
```

I have a service method in one of my services as follows --

```
public getContactInformation(Id: any): Observable<ContactInformationModel> {
        console.log('Service - ContactService - Method - getContactInformation - Params - Id  : ' + Id);
        this._requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            url: this.contactInformationUrl,
            headers: this.headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(Id)
        });
        console.log('POST Query for Contact Information : ' + JSON.stringify(this._requestOptions));
        return this._http.request(new Request(this._requestOptions)).map(this._httpExtractDataService.extractData).catch(this._httpErrorHandlerService.handleError);
}
```

I am calling the service from my component as follows --

```
//Get Contact Information
this._employeeFilesService.getEmployeeContactInformation(this.selectedEmployeeId).subscribe(
    data => this.contactDataItem = data,
    error => this._errorLoggerService.logError(error, "Contact Information Component"),
    () => console.log('Contact Information Received In Information Component -' + JSON.stringify(this.contactDataItem)));
```

Where contactDataItem is a variable of type ContactInformationModel, declared like this -

```
contactDataItem : ContactInformationModel;
```

When I run the application, I can see on console that the service is returning an object that looks like follows -

```
{
    "EmailAddress":"myofficeemail@email.com",
    "DirectPhone":"000-000-0000",
    "Extension":"0000",
    "DirectFax":"000-000-0000",
    "RemoteFax":"000-000-0000",
    "PersonalEmail":"mypersonalemail@email.com",
    "HomePhone":"000-000-0000",
    "CellPhone":"000-000-0000",
    "Birthday":"2017-05-10",
    "Address":"My Address",
    "PrimaryEmergencyContact":"Contact Person Name",
    "PrimaryEmergencyContactCellPhone":"000-000-0000",
    "SecondaryEmergencyContact":"Contact Person Name",
    "SecondaryEmergencyContactCellPhone":"000-000-0000"
}
```

but when I am trying to bind the properties of this object to the  of my table, then it is not getting binded.

```
<tbody>
    <tr><td><b>Email Address</b></td><td>{{contactDataItem?.EmailAddress}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Direct Phone</b></td><td>{{contactDataItem?.DirectPhone}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Extension</b></td><td>{{contactDataItem?.Extension}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Direct Fax</b></td><td>{{contactDataItem?.DirectFax}}</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Also, please be informed that when I am simply assigning a hardcoded object to the variable contactDataItem and binding it to the  then the binding is successfull.
What am I doing wrong ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Amit Anand

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: The error is  "Cannot find a differ supporting object"

Answer (score 0):

You could try accessing the data property.

```
    getMovie(id: number): Observable<IMovie> {
    const url = `${this.moviesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map((res: Response) => {
            const body = res.json();
            return <IMovie>body.data || {};
        })
        .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

From the Angular docs:

> Don't expect the decoded JSON to be the heroes array directly. This
>   server always wraps JSON results in an object with a data property.
>   You have to unwrap it to get the heroes. This is conventional web API
>   behavior, driven by security concerns.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Comment: No help using data.data. In fact, when I did this, it shows another error as 
"Property data does not exist on type ContactInformationModel"

Comment: OK, I have it in the wrong place in my answer. It should be in the service. I fixed the answer above, but wasn't sure what your `extractData` looked like, so I just pasted code from one of my apps.

Comment: This is how the extract data looks like

extractData(res: Response | any) {
        let body = res.json();
        
        return body || {};
    }

Comment: OK. So try the data property there: body.data (as in my revised answer)

Comment: Tried it, and now its returning undefined :-(

Comment: Which returns undefined and where?

Comment: the service method that was returning the object earlier is now returning undefined when I user body.data in extractData method

Comment: OK. Then your API does not seem to be wrapping the response in the data property. The 'diff' error you are getting is often generated when you are trying to use an array as an individual object. But you don't seem to be getting an array back?

Comment: Exactly, I am not getting an array back...I am getting an object in return (I have mentioned above how that object looks like when it is logged on console). Also, I tried to get an array in return and then bind the elements using *ngFor. In that case it works fine (since there is only one object in the array and so the objects properties are binded successfully). But when I am trying to bind using only the object then it throws that error.